# Is MRO order depth-first or breadth-first?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From *[Python in a Nutshell](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-in-a/9781098113544/)*:

> The lookup of an attribute name in a class essentially occurs by visiting ancestor
> classes in left-to-right, **depth-first order**

However,

```
>>> class A(object): x = 'a'
...
>>> class B(A): pass
...
>>> class C(A): x = 'c'
...
>>> class D(B, C): pass
...
>>> D.x
'c'
>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>,
    <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
```

`D.__mro__` lists the classes not in depth-first order, but breadth-first order. So do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Correct as far as I know. See https://youtu.be/EiOglTERPEo?t=32m32s

Comment: Also, depth-first really doesn't make sense. You could potentially have low-level objects calling high-level objects.

Comment: Here's a nice explanation of [C3 linearization method used in Python 2.3+](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

Comment: The issue with your quote is the word _"essentially"_. It means: For cases where there are no shared superclasses that are inherited more than once. As soon as that case happens, things become more complicated; see [donkopotamus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117600).

Answer (score 25):

Ignoring classic classes, Python resolves method and attribute lookups using the [C3 linearisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) of the class and its parents.  The C3 linearisation is **neither depth-first nor breadth-first** in complex multiple inheritance hierarchies.  In some sense, it is:

> depth-first until classes are encountered that will share a parent,
>   and then breadth-first over those

although that is a very loose characterisation.

In particular however, in simple multiple inheritance hierarchies that do not share a parent, it is **depth-first** (conveniently ignoring `object` of course, which is always shared)

#### Simple Example – Depth First

```
>>> class a_0(object): pass
>>> class a_1(object): pass
>>> class b_0(a_0): pass
>>> class b_1(a_1): pass
>>> class c(b_0, b_1): pass
```

Then

```
>>> [x.__name__ for x in c.__mro__]
['c', 'b_0', 'a_0', 'b_1', 'a_1', 'object']
```

#### Shared Base Example – Depth then Breadth First

Note that in your example, you have a shared parent (`A`) which causes `B` and `C` to be traversed in a breadth first fashion.  If you instead have an evern more complex hierarchy:

```
>>> class A(object): pass
>>> class B(A): pass
>>> class C(A): pass
>>> class D_0(B, C): pass
>>> class D_1(B, C): pass
>>> class E_0(D_0): pass
>>> class E_1(D_1): pass
>>> class F(E_0, E_1): pass
```

Then

```
>>> [x.__name__ for x in F.__mro__]
['F', 'E_0', 'D_0', 'E_1', 'D_1', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'object']
```

And you will observe that the search is depth first `F, E_0, D_0` until it strikes the point where shared base classes are encountered (`B` and `C` that are also bases of `D_1`, at which point the depth first goes sideways to `E_1` and depth first from there again.

Comment: For completeness, the canonical document on Python's mro is this: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/ (up to today (python 3.8), despite Python 2.3 figuring in the article's title)